# WSO2 IS 5.2: How do I a) set admin credentials, b) create API key and secret?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 with the Airavata science gateway software, and unfortunately some of the instructions for getting started are a little opaque. Two things I'm trying to accomplish:

1) set the "starting" admin username and password. As I understand it, these are set in WSO2 itself / its built in "H2" database, not whatever user/password store it's connected to such as LDAP. I can't find where to set that. I thought it was in user-mgt.xml, but the credentials you set there in the  tags appear not to do anything.

2) Airavata uses an API key and secret key to connect to WSO2 IS. I can't find anywhere in the WSO2 setup where this is created.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to set an existing admin user belonging an external user store such as LDAP. You can use the following section in user-mgt.xml

```
 <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>{Add_Your_Admin_User_Here}</UserName>
                <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
         ....
        </Configuration>
```

Change "AddAdmin" to false if you do not want to create a new admin user. You can keep the password as it is or leave it blank since it doesn't get used in this mode.

If you want to create a new one then keep the AddAdmin value to true and correct your user store in ReadWrite mode.

2) You should be able to find the under inbound authentication section of the Service Provider,

Service Providers --> [your service provide] --> Inbound Authentication Configuration --> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration